# Asp.Net Elements Doesn't Get Style Properties From Css File

Tags: asp.net, css

I don't know if there's a different Css usage in Asp.net but I just can't make it work.
I target my .css file with

```
<link href="Style/Style.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />
```

code.
 And there are `<div>` and `<table>` elements.
The table has an id and its properties in the css file are working normal. But I can't say the same thing about `<div>` and `<a>` tags.
Let's take this example:

```
<div align="center" id="bla">
```

And I use id in css file in different ways. I first used `#bla { }` or `div#bla` or `div #bla { }`, then I used `.bla { }` or `div.bla { }` or `div .bla { }` with making `class="bla"` instead of `id="bla"` in Aspx page, they all did not work.
But when I moved the code from css file to Aspx file between `<style type="text/css"><style/>` tags, it worked normal.
The same behaviour happens in `<a>` too. But it does not in `<table>`.
Is there a different usage? What do I miss?

More info at http://jsfiddle.net/npTc6/

Comment: You can use either the IE developer tool bar (in IE 7 or greater) or Firebug (for Firefox) to inspect an element and find where its style instructions are coming from. This will help you find where the instructions that are both being implemented and those that are being ignored are coming from.

Comment: Thanks, I did with IE9 Developer Toolbar. Everything looks normal there. It shows the properties in the css file. But when on show, It doesn't apply them. And this is outest div, not possible to get affected from an outer element. I'm about to go crazy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a pathing issue to your CSS file. If you have multiple CSS files, it could also be the order of your CSS files. You should verify that you have the correct path to your CSS file and that you have the correct file name referenced in your code. Often, the most simple mistakes are the most frustrating.

UPDATE:
Your CSS has a space between the "a" anchor and the class name, and I believe you need a leading slash on your image references (if not there already).

Example:

```
a .Russia
{
    display: block;
    background-image: url("/Images/Default/Russia.png");
    width: 173px;
    height: 173px;
}
```

try...

```
a.Russia
{
    display: block;
    background-image: url("/Images/Default/Russia.png");
    width: 173px;
    height: 173px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it applies the styles for table elements, only not with div or a. That makes me doubt about wrong path problem.

Comment: Don't think the align='center' will work. Are you trying to text align? If so, use <div style='text-align:center;'> In all honesty, that is not acceptable, because it is not a good standard to have inline styling. Keep your styling in your CSS file.

Comment: I have no problem with align or text-align. My problem is about background-image and its other properties.

Comment: How about posting your CSS and HTML?

Comment: I refresh with Ctrl+F5, I think that's what you meant. I tried in 3 different browsers also. I've uploaded my code to: http://jsfiddle.net/npTc6/

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem common in Asp.Net. Just about background properties. Standart CSS background-image code had some issues so there are variations. I tried many, then fixed it by using this one:
`background: url(/Images/Default/Turkiye.png);`

Comment: FYI, that was part of my suggestion in my answer. Hope you didn't spend too much time on that.

Comment: Was it? Sorry, I must've missed that point. I'm marking yours as the answer then. Thanks for that.